# Limit number of users from visiting particular page

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-side-scripting

When any user clicks on the link then they redirect to main index.php web page and from there by clicking on the button by below code they redirect to a random page from three which mentioned in below array. it is working perfectly fine. 
Now, I need to do a trick is that: for example, 75 users clicks on link and when 25 users redirect to **index_control.php** then more worker should not redirect to **index_control.php** page then only other two pages has to be open for remaining users to redirect. in short limit the number of visit to each page to 25. 
anyone could give a idea how to do that?

```
<html>
<button onclick="randomLink();">Click here to go somewhere else!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

var randomLink = function () {      
    var links = [
        "index_non_intrusive.php",
        "index_control.php",
        "index_intrusive.php"];   
    var max = (links.length)   
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);

    var link = links[randomNumber];
    window.location = link;
     //window.location = "http://" + link;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You would need to store the number in a server side variable somewhere. You could use caching, database, etc.

Comment: You can't do that in javascript on the client side, unless you give the information to the script how many users there are on the page. This kind of redirect should be made on the server side. Since you give the links in the script there is nothing that prevents a user from manually going to the a page of their choice.

Comment: @Forklift I am storing information such as their navigation from which page to which page they are going for all three pages in three different tables on server side database with their some id. kind of log of their clicks on Html links. So I could use i think SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT custid)FROM non_intrusive_audit" to count unique users visit from their id but I am not getting how to restrict the numbers for each page

Comment: If you know how many times each page has been visited, you should be able to remove them from your random function whenever they reach 25.